# how to create li and a tag in array using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I can't to make a dropdown button in array using `javascript`.

How to create link to `li`.?

How to create a `create.element("li")` and `create.Element("a")` both.?

Here is the code:

```
var select = document.getElementById('ul'),
  array = ["html", "css", "js", "jquery", "Angularjs"];

for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
  var option = document.createElement("li"),
    txt = document.createTextNode(array[i]);
  option.appendChild(txt);
  select.insertBefore(option, select.lastChild);
}
```

Comment: share ur html please

Comment: What is the problem you currently have? Can you give a [mcve] so that we can reproduce your problems?

Comment: if you need dropdown you need `select > option` and not `ul > li` right?

Comment: @AakashThakur HTML <ul id="ul"></ul>, now i had created a li but i want to create a link

Comment: @KresimirPendic i already did that with the help of option. but i wanted in ul > li.

Comment: Hi if any below answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself.

Comment: @Bhuwan your answer is correct i solved it.

Answer (score 1):

Try to create a `<a>` tag and then append it to `<li>`

***Stack Snippet***

```js
var select = document.getElementById('ul');
var array = ["html", "css", "js", "jquery", "Angularjs"];

for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
  var li = document.createElement("li");
  var link = document.createElement("a");
  link.setAttribute('href', '#');
  li.appendChild(link);
  var text = document.createTextNode(array[i]);
  link.appendChild(text);
  select.insertBefore(li, select.childNodes[i]);
}
```

```css
ul {
  font: 13px Verdana;
}

ul>li>a {
  color: red;
  text-transform: capitalize
}
```

```html
<ul id="ul"></ul>
```

Comment: why `insertBefore(li, select.lastChild)`? you are messing order this way

Comment: after the line `var link = document.createElement("a");` You can add `link.href` to add link to the anchors

Comment: @pwolaq Thanks for noticing....Updated..!

Comment: @pwolaq just replace select.insertBefore(li, select.childNodes[i]); with select.appendChild(li, select.lastChild);

Comment: @TanmayGawankar added the href attribute too...but its not which OP asked...BTW thanks for the suggestion..

Comment: @Timo see...there are many ways to do it...so I don't think there is need to replace it

Comment: @BhuwanBhatt Thanks so much I really need this thing.I had tried so many times to create a link and append it but failed. now is perfect

Comment: @pwolaq thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

```js
const select = document.querySelector('ul')
const array = [ "html","css","js","jquery","Angularjs" ]

const markup = array.map(item => `<li><a href="#">${item}</a></li>`).join(' ')

select.innerHTML = markup
```

```html
<ul></ul>
```

Comment: this can lead to security vulnerabilities

Comment: @VilleKoo thank you so much.very short and easy code really works.

Comment: @pwolaq thanks for pointing that out. What do you think about [this](http://wesbos.com/sanitize-html-es6-template-strings/) solution?

Answer (score -1):

can't you use JQuery?

```
$("#content ul").append('<li><a href="//"><span class="tab">Message</span></a></li>');
```

Comment: so you suggest downloading few kbs of code to save few lines?

Comment: @DiSaSteR nope. only use pure JavaScript,